# Prove that $n^{91}≡n^7 \pmod{28}$ for all integers $n.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have trouble to start with this question, please help

Comment: note that 7|(21+70). so i guess proving this, will prove a bigger statement.

Answer (score 2):

Its special case $\,k=7,\ \phi = 84\,$ in the following generalization of [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\rm\color{blue}{(E)}$

**Theorem** $\ \ \, n^{\large k+\phi}\equiv n^{\large k}\pmod{p^i q^j}\ \ $ if $\,p\ne q\,$ are prime, $ \ \color{#0a0}{\phi(p^i),\phi(q^j)\mid \phi},\, $  $\, i,j \le k.\ \ \ $

${\bf Proof}\,\ \ p\nmid n\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod\ }p^i\!:\  n^{ \phi}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, n^{k + \phi}\equiv n^k,\ $ by $\,\  n^{\Large \color{#0a0}\phi} = (n^{\color{#0a0}{\Large \phi(p^{ i})}})^{\Large \color{#0a0}\ell}\overset{\color{blue}{\rm (E)}}\equiv 1^{\large \ell}\equiv 1$

$\qquad\quad\ \ \color{#c00}{p\mid n}\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod\ }p^i\!:\  n^k\equiv 0\,\equiv\, n^{k + \phi}\ $ by $\ n^k = n^{k-i} \color{#c00}n^i = n^{k-i} (\color{#c00}{mp})^i$ and $\,k\ge i$

So $\ p^i\mid n^{k+\phi}\!-n^k.\,$ By symmetry $\,q^j$ divides it too, so their lcm $ = p^iq^j\,$ divides it too. $\ $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ The proof immediately extends to an arbitrary number of primes. See also [Carmichael's Lambda function,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) a generalization of [Euler's phi function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Answer (score 1):

$28=7*4$, thus $Z/28=Z/4\times Z/7$ by the Chinese remainder.

$n^7=n$ mod $7$ by Little fermat, $n^{91}=(n^7)^{13}$ mod 7= $n^{13}$ mod 7. Little fermat says $n^6=1$ mod 7, so $n^{6++6+1}=n$ mod 7.

$n^7=0$ mod 4=$n^{91}$ mod 4 if $n$ is even.

$n^7=1$ mod 4=$n^{91}$ mod 4 if $n=1$ mod 4.

$n^7=-11$ mod 4=$n^{91}$ mod 4 if $n=-1$ mod 4